# how to concatenate two string from 2 list in one list without getting double quotation doubled?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, numpy

**i have two list i want to have concatenation without additional quote ,and those  lists that i want to enter**

```py
a=["a"]
b=["b"]
```

** how i can pass it in matrix like this**

```py
matrix["ab"]
```

** or how i can get this result , i try append and concatenate but it doesn't work**

```py
c=["ab"]
```

Comment: What are your problems? Which code did lead to your _doesn't work_ and what does not work?

Comment: i want to do this code
import blosum as bl
matrix = bl.BLOSUM(62)                                                                                                                  a=["A"]
b=["C"]                                                                                                                                                 c="AC"                                                                                                                                           val = matrix["AC"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
d = list([a[0]+b[0]])
```

or use the code below which also combines strings from longer lists such as ['a', 'c'] and ['b', 'e']

```
d = [i+j for i, j in zip(a,b)]
```